# Refresh a PostgreSQL materialized view automatically without using triggers

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-9.5, materialized-view

I created a materialized view named `view_table_A` on a foreign data wrapper table `table_A`. What I want is for the view to be automatically updated after every new insert in `table_A`. I tried to do this with triggers but it didn't work.

Is it possible to refresh a materialized view automatically without using triggers?

Comment: Why didnt it work using triggers? It should (?)

Answer (score 14):

As [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) said in a comment:

> No, that's not possible. You need some kind of scheduler that runs refresh materialized view e.g. [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) or something on the operating system level – a_horse_with_no_name

Alternatively, if you need a `MATERIALIZED VIEW` that refreshes when you run `SELECT`, just remove `MATERIALIZED` and use a regular `VIEW`. Materialization only adds a periodic cache. It's only needed when the query itself is prohibitively slow or hot.